# How do you hide parts of a sculpted mesh while "Textured Solid" is checked?

Tags: sculpting

I have an application where I'm trying to sculpt a complex mesh to match a textured plane. The problem is sometimes I need to hide parts of the mesh I'm sculpting, to access inner parts, but with the "Textured Solid" box checked, the entire mesh is shown, even the hidden parts.

Right now I need to toggle the "Textured Solid" on and off while I'm sculpting in order to get what I need to do.

This first picture shows how it looks with "textured solid" off, and the next with it on. Hopefully this makes it clear what I need and what the problem is.

[image: Textured Solid *off*]

[image: Textured solid *on*]

Comment: Why not making textured plane ineditable but visible, and continue sculpting with it positioned so to see the details needed ? You can also add **Displace** modifier, subdivide the plane enough, and set that texture for the modifier. It will make the mesh geometry being protruded in places where the texture is brighter and you'll be able to see that even if not using Textured mode.

Comment: may the mask modifier help you, hiding part of the mesh?

Comment: @mrzak I'm clearly not a very good blender user because I didn't understand what you meant, sorry about that but could you clarify? Is there a gui option for making an object ineditable? As far as your second suggestion, I tried a displace modifier with a texture but it still vanishes when the textured solid is unchecked

Comment: @m.ardito found that mask modifier, and it may helpful thank you for your comment

Comment: Probably I wasn't clear; I meant make the object unselectable, pressing [mouse cursor icon in Outliner editor](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html?highlight=outliner#toggling-object-level-restrictions). For **Displace** modifier, it's better to unwrap the plane and setup modifier accordingly (selecting UV in its options); also plane should be subdivided *very much* (about 2k polys) in order to see the texture clearly on it while in 3D View without having Texture Solid. Regarding to **Mask** modifier, unfortunately it won't work in Sculpt mode.

Comment: @m.ardito unfortunately the mask modifier is not helpful for me. If I apply the mask modifier, there is no way to recover the hidden parts. If I use the mask to hide (enable and disable) without applying, then it does not prevent sculpting to the hidden parts :( its too bad because it sounded really promising.

Comment: @MrZak oops,should have refreshed the page before trying the mask modifier,since you knew already.    Trying the unelectable didn't seem to help me. I need to be able to translate the plane. There is a script I wrote that will update the texture on the plane as it translates so I can "slice" the 3d volume I'm tracing interactively

Comment: I tried also "masking" with boolean modifier, but it seems to not work either... well it hides visually part of the mesh, but even the hidden part it is affected by the sculpt... if you sculpt where is hidden... if not clear, I can elaborate more... tomorrow :)

Comment: @m.ardito yes that's the problem I found when trying to use masking, so unfortunately it's not appropriate. Well for now I'll just have to do the long way around. Would be nice if there was an option for this.